# Convert.ToDecimal from input string ignores dots but accepts comma

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, decimal, decimal-point

I have this small piece of code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace project
{
    class conditionalStatements
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number greater than 45.2");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            decimal answer_decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(answer);
            // decimal answer_decimal = Decimal.Parse(answer);
            decimal compareValue = 45.2m;

            Console.WriteLine(answer_decimal);
            //prints 452

            if(Decimal.Compare(answer_decimal, compareValue) > 0){
                // stuff
            }
            else{
                // should enter here
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

The problem is that since both the method `Convert.ToDecimal()` and `Decimal.Parse()` ignore the dot notation of decimal values (or at least that's what's happening to me) the number is interpreted as `452` instead of `45.2`. No matter how many dots I input. In fact, if I were to enter:

```
45......2
```

the converted value still would be converted to `452`. **Only if** I use the comma, then the converted number is correctly interpreted as `45.2` and I am able to enter the `else` condition.

I did not change the `NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator`. I left it as default `'.'`

Comment: What culture is associated with the thread?

Comment: An advice not related to your current problem. Never try to use Convert.ToXXXX on user input. If the user types invalid numbers your code will raise an exception. In these contexts always use _decimal.TryParse_

Answer (score 0):

Convert input string to decimal with a given culture that treats dot as decimal separator:

```
decimal answer_decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(answer, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: The question states that the decimal separator (at least for currency) is already `'.'`.

Comment: This solves the problem with the dot. But what if I wanted to use both? Becuase in this case, now the same problem occurs with the comma. Isn't there a way to accept them both? Thank you very much for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the code below:

```
decimal answer_decimal; 
while(!decimal.TryParse(answer, out answer_decimal)){
    Console.WriteLine("Value entered could not be converted.");
}
decimal compareValue = 45.2m;

        Console.WriteLine(answer_decimal);
        //prints 452

        if(Decimal.Compare(answer_decimal, compareValue) > 0){
            // stuff
        }
        else{
            // should enter here
        }
```

This way you prevent the program from crashing if the conversion is not possible.
If you want to use a specific culture you can do so by using an overload of decimal.TryParse as follows:

```
decimal.TryParse(answer, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("EN-us"), out answer_decimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your culture set to Dari?

I think the applicable [`NumberFormatInfo` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo) would be [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator), not [`CurrencyDecimalSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimalseparator). `decimal.Parse()`, called directly or via `Convert.ToDecimal()`, would have no idea currency is what's being parsed unless a [`NumberStyles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles) value with one of the `*Currency*` flags were passed.

When an overload of `decimal.Parse()` is called that does not accept a `NumberStyles` parameter it defaults to [`NumberStyles.Number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles#System_Globalization_NumberStyles_Number).  This composite style includes the [`NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles#System_Globalization_NumberStyles_AllowDecimalPoint) style, the documentation for which states (emphasis mine)...

> If the `NumberStyles` value includes the `AllowCurrencySymbol` flag and the parsed string includes a currency symbol, the decimal separator character is determined by the `CurrencyDecimalSeparator` property.  **Otherwise, the decimal separator character is determined by the `NumberDecimalSeparator` property.**

Now, are there actually any cultures that use different decimal separators for numbers and currency?  Let's find out...

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .Where(culture => culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator != culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
```

On .NET Framework v4.7.2 that yields a small number of cultures...

```
fr-CH
kea
kea-CV
mr
mr-IN
prs
prs-AF
pt-CV
```

Tweaking that LINQ query to account for the specific behavior you're seeing (currency decimal separator is `"."`, number decimal separator is `","`, number group separator is `"."`)...

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .Where(culture => culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator == ".")
    .Where(culture => culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator == ",")
    .Where(culture => culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator == ".");
```

...narrows it down to two Dari cultures...

```
prs
prs-AF
```

Sure enough, if I change my culture to Dari beforehand...

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("prs");
```

...on my system your code behaves exactly as you described.  If you don't want to use your culture's separators the solution, of course, is to specify at the system, thread, or method level a specific or custom culture with the separators you *do* want.